# Reposting an old post

Tags: discussion

I have found few old posts in P SE in which asked questions are not clear. So no one has answered it or it has ambiguous answers in it. Is it possible for someone else other than the author to modify the contents of the post and re post it, so it can be useful to others. The reason I am asking this is- I don't think it is considered to be a good practice to change the content of the post without the permission of the author. But with little modification of the corresponding post it would be helpful to others.

I am not talking about edits for punctuation or grammar etc.. I am talking about the main content of the post. By asking 'Is it possible' I don't mean 'Is it possible?' I am asking the validity according to the etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're really old, go ahead and clarify them via edits. The edit will bump it to the front page, where it will get some attention. If the post is a closed post, flag it with a custom message asking for a reopen.

To get more attention for them, you may want to [place a bounty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties)

If you're still afraid of editing, you *may* re-ask, make sure to link to the original in the comments and say that it isn't that well phrased. In such a case, we may close the older one (if it has no valuable answers) as a dupe of the new one. But I discourage doing this -- it should only be in cases where the question is extremely vague (and thus unclarifiable by anyone but the OP) and the answers are worthless. In this case, remember to flag the old question as `It doesn't belong here`>`Not A Real Question` if it isn't closed already. (Actually, any vague/ambiguous/incomplete question you see should be flagged as such if you're not editing it)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible for someone else other than the author to modify the contents of the post

Yes, this is possible and encouraged when appropriate.

> and re post it

Possible, yes, but don't do that. It'll get closed as a duplicate.

If you would like an old question to get attention, surely you can find something to improve in it. Fixing punctuation or grammar is always a good idea, of course; you can also check the tags, improve the title, etc. Very few (if any) questions are "perfectly" written. Making any edit of this sort will bump the question up to the front page so it can get renewed attention. Just make sure your edit actually improves the post.

You can also set a bounty on a post you would like to see get more attention.